# an analytic function from unit disk to unit disk with two fixed point

Tags: complex-analysis

prove that if  $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ is analytic with two distinct fixed point then $f$ is identity.

I thought if one of the fixed points was zero by schwarz lemma this statement is easily proved.

but what can I do if fixed points were nonzero?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I thought if one of the fixed points were zero by the Schwarz lemma this statement is easily proved.

Good. So it remains to reduce the general case to the known special case.

Let $T$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$. What do you know about $T^{-1}\circ f \circ T$? Can you find a condition on $T$ that reduces the problem to the known case?

Comment: it is a function from $\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$  that fixes zero! am i right?

Comment: Whether it fixes zero depends on $T$. What condition on $T$ makes it fix zero?

Comment: no sorry!it is a function from $\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ that fixes $T^{-1}$ (fixed  point of f)! am i right?

Comment: Yes. That's right. So what condition on $T$ do you want?

Comment: i want $T(0)=$ fixed point of f.

Comment: Yup. I guess you know that that is always possible, and you can probably write down such a $T$ explicitly.

Comment: I don't understand. If $h:=T^{-1} \circ f \circ T$, we have $h(0)=0$. But if we use Schwarz lemma, we get $h(z)=cz$ for all $z \in \mathbb D$ and some $c \in \mathbb C$ and that implies $f(z)=T(cT^{-1}(z))$ for all $z \in \mathbb D$, but why does that imply $f(z)=z$?

Comment: @Twink $f$ has (at least) two fixed points, hence so has $h$. Let $\zeta\neq 0$ be another fixed point. Then you can deduce $c =\:?$