# Analytic function with only one fixed point in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $|z|\le 1$ and satisfy $|f(z)|<1$ if $|z|=1$. Show that $f$ has a unique fixed point on $|z|<1$, namely a unique point $z_0$ in the disk $|z|<1$ such that $f(z_0)=z_0$.

---

My solution:

Since $f$ is an analytic, hence continuous function from the closed disk to itself ([Maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle)), then $f$ has at least one fixed point according to the [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Statement). Now it leaves us to check that there is only *one* fixed point.

Whereas, we have known that [if $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ is analytic with two distinct fixed points then $f$ is identity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/801570/497335) contradicting the condition that $|f(z)|<1$ if $|z|=1$. And we are done.

---

My question is, can we avoid the Brouwer fixed-point theorem here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(z)=f(z)-z$. By the hypothesis and Rouche’s theorem, $g$ has the same number of zeros as $-z$ in the disk $|z|<1$, which is one.